# Subnet mask changing to '24' on Fedora Web Panel

Tags: fedora

I keep having an issue with my Fedora 27 Server Edition on the Web panel where it will keep changing my subnet mask from 255.255.255.0 to 24 without any explanation.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that is changes the subnet mask from 255.255.255.0 to 24. Then don't worry it is the same thing. There are 24 bits in 3 bytes. You have set the first 3 bytes to all ones. 255 = binary 11111111.

In the first form, you could set an incorrect mask of `255.0.255.0` however it is not valid, as it results in 11111111 00000000 11111111 00000000. All masks must be a run of 1s then a run of 0s.

The newer way to specify a mask just states how many 1s there are.

255.255.255.0 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 = 24 ones

Comment: Ah that makes sense, the connection seems to be fine in terms of connecting to google, youtube and such. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you like an answer, then it is traditional here to click the tick ✓.